# products/factoring of two hypergraphs with same vertex set?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, hypergraph, reference-request

all the basic products for graphs have been extended to hypergraphs[1].

> is there a concept of a product of hypergraphs with the same vertex set? has this been studied?

normally the hypergraph product is between two hypergraphs $H_1 = (V_1, \mathscr{E}_1), H_2 = (V_2, \mathscr{E}_2)$. am asking about the case $V_1=V_2$. (have an idea for a defn of this but am looking for any other preexisting cases first. esp interested in factoring)

[1] [Hypergraph products](http://lips.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/files/diplom_0.pdf) by Hellmuth

[2] mathoverflow, [What are the Applications of Hypergraphs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13750/what-are-the-applications-of-hypergraphs)

Comment: What do you want to use such a concept for? 

Comment: @qiaochu seems to be an application in CS/complexity theory/EE. see also better description here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/108655/hypergraph-cartesian-join-operation-over-same-vertex-set