# Seven Bridges of Königsberg for hypergraphs

Tags: graph-theory, teaching, hypergraph

I am teaching a course involving hypergraphs. I would like to have a physical analogy/motivating problem for hypergraphs similarly to how the Seven Bridges of Königsberg motivate graphs. Can you help me out?

Comment: Hypergraphs are *extremely general* objects (sets of subsets, basically), and somehow slightly less "visual" than graphs are, so it's hard to give something that feels very concrete.

Comment: But for something very classic: the "Happy Ending Problem" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_ending_problem) can be resolved using hypergraph Ramsey numbers (for specifically 3-uniform hypergraphs).

Answer (score 4):

Imagine a virus spreads between individuals when they are in the same room. Then, consider the hypergraph where each hyperedge is the set of individuals who happened to be together in a same room. It may represent the **network on which the virus spreads** (although adding time information seems needed).

More generally, since hypergraphs are equivalent to bipartite graphs, they model many real-world situations.

Another example is the **co-authoring hypergraph**, in which each paper leads to an hyperedge between its authors. It is used to study the structure of scientific fields.

In recommender systems, one also considers **hypergraphs over products**, where hyperedges are sets of products bought by a same client.

The [wikipedia hypergraph page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph#Applications) has some pointers to various applications.

Also, there is a great discussion here, that mentions many math-oriented examples:
[What are the applications of hypergraphs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13750/what-are-the-applications-of-hypergraphs)

I hope this helps, good luck with your course!